# Search data table with Date

Tags: php, mysql, date, search, html-table

I have a data table which is the result of one form submission, the form has start_date and end_date where its type is `DATETIME-LOCAL`.

In my database its `DATETIME` (not showing AM and PM),
I want to add search function to my data table based on the date not date and time,

Other type of search based on TYPE and NAME are working but date doesn't show nor error and results.

```
<form action="search.php" id="searchform" method="POST" class="searchbox-container">
    <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search" name="searchbox" class="searchbox" />
    <input type="date" name="date">

    <select name="select" id="select">
        <option value="type">Type</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="search" class="searchbox-btn" value="Go" />

</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $search=preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i','',$_POST['searchbox']);


        $user="admin";
        $pass="neehahs";
        $host="localhost";
        $db_name="eventregisteration";

        $con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $date=$_POST['date'];


        if($_POST['select']=="type"){
            $sqlcommand="SELECT * FROM eventform WHERE event_type LIKE '%$search%'";    


        }
        elseif($_POST['select']=="name"){
            $sqlcommand="SELECT * FROM eventform WHERE event_name LIKE '%$search%'";        


        }
        else {
            if($date!=0)
                $sqlcommand="SELECT * FROM eventform WHERE start_date='$date' ORDER BY start_date DESC";    


        }
        $sqldata=mysqli_query($con,$sqlcommand)
            or die("Error Getting Data");

        $count=mysqli_num_rows($sqldata);
        if($count!=0){

            echo "<table border=2 bordercolor=#440000 cellpadding=2 bgcolor=#DDDDDD width=100%>";
            echo "<tr bgcolor=#555555 style=font-size:18px align=center><th>Event Code</th><th>Event Name</th><th>Event Type</th><th>Event Level</th><th>Start Date</th>
      <th>End Date</th><th>Point</th><th>Picture</th><th>Video</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)){
                echo "<tr align=center><td>";
                echo $row['event_code'];

                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['event_name'];
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo $row['event_type'];
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo $row['event_level'];
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo $row['start_date'];
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo $row['end_date'];
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo $row['points'];
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo "<a href=http://localhost/greenstudio/".$row['pic'].">".$row['pic']."</a>";
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo "<a href=http://localhost/greenstudio/".$row['video'].">".$row['video']."</a>";
                echo "</td><td>";

                echo $row['description'];
                echo "</td></tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";

        }else{
            echo "hi";
            $search_output="<hr/>0 Results for<strong>$search</strong><hr/>";

        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query written in an index-friendly manner might look like this

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM eventform
 WHERE start_date >= '$date'
   AND start_date < '$date' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

where `$date` should be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (e.g. `2013-11-27`)

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45b97/3)** demo

**On a side note:** since you already using `mysqli` consider to learn and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of interpolating query strings leaving it wide open to sql injections.